# Как использовать скомпилированные библиотеки в Android проекте с помощью NDK?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, library

я хочу создать в Android Studio программу, которая создает pvrtc2 или pvrt4 сжатые текстуры из png файлов. Я нашел эти библиотеки, созданные Imagination:
[image: libraries]

А также пример кода на c++:

[image: code]

Но я новичок в c++ , посмотрел множество туториалов по jdi и NDK в Android Studio, но так и не смог разобраться как использовать большую C библиотеку, т.к. эти туториалы ограничиваются настройкой jdi и созданием c файла с 2-4 строчками кода... Есть ли способ добавить pvrtexlib в мой проект с помощью NDK и вызывать через jdi внутренние функции? И если да, то может быть есть какой-то нормальный урок по этой теме. Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: Тут говорят по-русски.

Comment: ок, как задать вопрос в англоязычном stakoverflow? пробежался по вопросам, думаю в русскоязычном сообществе мало кто в этом разбирается

Comment: открыть stackoverflow.com. Но здесь Вы тоже можете получить ответ, я считаю.

Comment: спасибо, решил отредактировать здесь, теперь вопрос на русском